# how to identify encryption or hash value type

Tags: encryption, hash

I have this hash or encrypted string 
    861004c2-a9e0-4dae-a436-f46cecf14591
please tell me which encryption or hash algorithms used to generate values like this and how can I decrypt it. i already search web for this string type and check previews threads related to the encryption and hash methods but fail to identify this string.
thanks

Comment: It more looks like a [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is impossible to determine which algorithm produced this output, because ciphertexts and hash outputs are supposed to be indistinguishable from random noise. This question doesn't have any value for future readers and we're not here to play the [guessing game](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/).

Comment: I am extremely sorry if it's off-topic Artjom, I was searching this type of strings from long time to know the algorithms used to hash or encrypt this finally got my answer :)

Comment: @vishalSingh It's good that you have your answer, but it's highly unlikely that somebody will find your question trying to identify a similar string.

Comment: @ArtjomB. yes I know can you please suggest better format so I can edit the question in better way

Comment: @vishalSingh Sorry, I can't think of how it can be better phrased.

Comment: okay so what you suggest i delete this question or leave it as it is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the byte values alone it is impossible to distinguish which algorithm was used.  It is a desired characteristic of hashes and encryption algorithms that though they are deterministic, their output is indistinguishable from real randomness.  It follows that they are also indistinguishable from one another.

Now the formatting may help, as in Hamed's post it may indicate a GUID.  But there is no way to know based on the byte values alone.

Comment: Please don't answer bad and off-topic questions, even if you know "the answer". You can't be sure. By answering those questions, you explicitly acknowledge that those are good questions and are a good fit for StackOverflow which they are not. We're not here to play the [guessing game](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/), but create a library of good content for good *answerable* questions.

Comment: It was doubly good advice.  I've found that the same people who ask low quality questions also generally have a poor record of interacting with those trying to help them.

Answer (score 0):

It looks llike a GUID. GUIDs have different versions and each version's algorithm differs.

For example, Version 1 GUIDs are generated based on the user's network card MAC address and the time while generating the GUID. Version 4 GUIDs use a pseudo-random number.

For more information check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier#Algorithm).

Comment: Please don't answer bad and off-topic questions, even if you know "the answer". You can't be sure. By answering those questions, you explicitly acknowledge that those are good questions and are a good fit for StackOverflow which they are not. We're not here to play the [guessing game](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/), but create a library of good content for good *answerable* questions.

Comment: @Artjom I agree with you on most of the part, but sometimes people have good question but they know how to ask it, our comments and answers might help them to have a clear view of what they want

Comment: Yes, it's a judgment call if you prioritize helping a fellow user any way you can or want to keep SO clean. The problem with this type of question is that if the OP gets even a single answer ("correct" or not), then the community must close and delete the question, because it's not useful for future readers. You have to always think about how users are going to find this question. I can't think of a single string that they type into their favorite search engine that gives them this question and is useful to them. It might pop up in unrelated searches which is a waste of time for them and you.